# Bendy bones acting weird

Tags: rigging

Im trying to work with bendy bones and what I have is a pre build segment of bone the behaves exactly the way I need it to the only issue is while im trying to rig it up to my character it gets all wanky and messes up

Ill grab the bottom control point in edit mode in order to stretch it to the length of the leg and it will look fine while in edit mode but once I go to object mode it shoots off into all kind of directions.

Anyone know whats going on?[image]

Comment: could you share your file (at least the armature)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here you go [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6100" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6100/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've changed the *Rest Length* of your bendy bone, so click on the *Reset* button to bring it back to its normal value. Also, in the *Bone* panel, don't forget to give this bone its *Start Handle* and *End Handle* bones (well, if you need).

[image]